# How to avoid repetition in array filling

Tags: java, arrays, repeat

I have the next code and what I want to do is to check whether I have  a value inside an array or not. The problem is, my code does the comparison just between the value I give as a parameter and the last value in the array, what I want to check is to see of I have the value and then return the boolean true, but my code just compare last value in the array. The code is here:

```
public boolean trueIdTienda(String s) {
    boolean f = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < lista.size(); x++) {
        if (s.equals(ventas.getVenta(x).getIdTienda())) {
            f = true;
        } else {
            f = false;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep your completely unpractical code alive, put the `break` after the `f = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic search algorithm:

```
public boolean trueIdTienda(String s) {
    for (int x = 0; x < lista.size(); x++) {
        if (s.equals(ventas.getVenta(x).getIdTienda())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I like this one the most...I am going to use this one! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This part is not needed:

```
 else {
        f = false;
    }
```

Since if one of them match it is a match, you don't need to set it back to `true`. Also you could return after a match, to speed the code up a bit (and more logical).

If you let the `else` part stay there, it will set the value back to `false` once it find a non-equal. Consider finding `[1, 2]` for `1` and you will see.

Comment: @DuncanJones I agree this answer is a bit trivial, but I read the OP's questions as "why doesn't this function shout out a true when needed".

Comment: Thanks, it works!! but what is the difference between do an else and not do the else?

Comment: This is a big part of the problem, at least.  The code is only checking the last item because the match status is getting reset every time.  (Course, if you returned rather than just setting a flag, this wouldn't be an issue...and the code would be more efficient besides. :P  But this would pretty much fix the problem too.)

Comment: I deleted my previous comment - I misread the question and thus your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Your function can be simplified to immediately return `true` if the value is found.

```
public boolean trueIdTienda(String s) {
    for (int x = 0; x < lista.size(); x++) {
        if (s.equals(ventas.getVenta(x).getIdTienda())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks to all of you...i am sorry i cant vote you, my reputation is less than 15 sorry but thanks to all, all the answers are working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Collection. something like a Hash should help you
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/Createuniquelistsofitems.htm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although you find that a value in the array is equal to the argument you set the boolean true and continue comparing with other values which return the boolean to false.

Final value of the boolean is the result of comparing with the last value, what solves the problem is to add `break;` after `f=true;`

Try to understand what caused your problem not simply using a correct code.